# How to group this dataframe by 'Continent' column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

A 'Continent' column is added to an existing data frame using a dictionary to match with the country names in data frame.
I am trying to group the data frame by the 'Continent' column.

I have tried the following:

```
def answer_eleven():
    Top15 = answer_one()
    ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
    ContinentDict= pd.Series(ContinentDict)
    Top15= Top15.assign(Continent= ContinentDict)
    Top15= Top15.groupby('Continent')
    return Top15
answer_eleven()
```

However, the output i get is:
pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000021C9C3BC6D8

Comment: Give your groupby an aggregate function to tell it how to group. What is your `top15` by? `groupby('continent').count()` perhaps?

Comment: Maybe am unable to understand how group by works. Yes I want to group by count, but how do I use an aggregate function with it?

Comment: Exaclty as I showed, you add your agg func to your groupby (`.count(), .sum(), .first()`). It's a bit confusing when you start learning it, but imagine it's lazily evaluated like a list generator. The data is grouped, but until you tell it how to treat the other columns, it won't gather or display the grouped DF

Answer (score 0):

a way to display a groupby object is

```
data = answer_eleven() 

for key, item in data:
    print(data.get_group(key), "\n")
```